# How to determine referer in Nitrogen?

Tags: erlang, referrer, nitrogen

I know about $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in PHP, and I believe there is something as simple as that in Nitrogen, but I just can't find it in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`wf:header(referer)`](http://nitrogenproject.com/doc/api.html#sec-12), I think.